Question regarding two beginner inductive hypothesis proofs in Propositional Logic
I am currently studying the semantics of PL, and there are two exercises in the book that ask me to prove the following by induction:

Show that for every $n \geq 0$: $(A_1 \wedge, A_2 \wedge, ..., \wedge A_n) \rightarrow B \Leftrightarrow (A_1 \rightarrow (A_2 \rightarrow ...(A_n \rightarrow B))$ (That is, that any formulae in this "shape" are logically equivalent).

Show that for every $n \geq 1$: $Q_n \leftrightarrow (Q_{n-1} \leftrightarrow (... \leftrightarrow (Q_1 \leftrightarrow Q_0)...))$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\neg Q_n \leftrightarrow (Q_{n-1} \leftrightarrow (... \leftrightarrow (Q_1 \leftrightarrow \neg Q_0)...))$.


For the second one, I am stumped. I'm not looking exactly for a solution (although that would be nice, at least as an anchor point to check whether I'm reasoning alright), but more of the idea for the thing.
For the first one, I think I have it down but I'm unsure whether it is as watertight as I believe it to be, or whether it can be shortened.
Base Case (n = 0):
Since n = 0, we have $B \Leftrightarrow B$ which is trivially true.
Inductive Hypothesis:
Assume the statement holds for $A_n$, we show it holds for $A_{n+1}$.
Either $V(A_{n+1}) = 1$ or $V(A_{n+1}) = 0$. By the IH we know that for $n$ the left-hand formula is true/false iff the right-hand formula is true/false.
We consider the case were both formulas are true first.
$(A_1 \wedge ... \wedge A_n) \rightarrow B$ = 1 iff either $(A_1 \wedge ... \wedge A_n) = 0$ or $B=1$.
If it is the case that $(A_1 \wedge ... \wedge A_n) = 0$, then $\exists A_i$ for $1 \geq i \geq n$ such that $V(A_i) = 0$. Since, by IH, the right-hand formula is true, we have three cases to inspect: when $A_i$ = 1, when $A_i = n$ or when $A_i$ is strictly between $1$ and $n$. If $A_i = 1$ we are done, because the valuation of $(A_2 ... A_n \rightarrow (A_{n+1} \rightarrow B))$ does not matter. If $A_i$ is between $1$ and $n$, then we are also done as the valuation of all $A_k$ for $k > i$ (including n+1) does not matter. Finally, in case $A_n = 0$, the same reasoning as the previous case applies and we are done.
In the case where $B = 1$, we are done as for $V(A_{n+1}) = 1$ or $V(A_{n+1}) = 0$ both left and right formulas are true.
Now consider the case where both formulas are false.
$(A_1 \wedge, ... \wedge A_n) \rightarrow B$ is false iff $(A_1 \wedge, ... \wedge A_n)$ is true and $B$ is false. This means all $A_n$ are true, which means $A_{n+1}$ must be true. In this case, $(A_n \rightarrow B)$ return false, and therefore $A_n \rightarrow (A_{n+1} \rightarrow B)$ also returns false. Since all previous A are true, the whole formula returns false.

For the first equivalence, you might want to see this question and answer. The second equivalence is really unclear to me. How would you write it out for n = 1 or n = 2?
